# Inducing metric of a vector space

Tags: vector-spaces

What does it mean, in the context of normed vector spaces, that the norm *induces* the metric? Furthermore, why normal vector spaces can't have a metric and be considered a metric space then?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a norm on your vector space. It tells you *more* than just the distance between points. So it induces a metric because it tells you what the metric is, i.e. $d(x,y)=||x-y||$, but a norm is *more* than just a metric.

Un-normed vector spaces *can* be metric, but it's classic result that there is only one vector space topology on a finite dimensional vector space over $\mathbb{R}$, and this topology is necessarily normed.

In infinite dimension, I guess the most classic example is $C^{\infty}(K)$ for some compact $K\subseteq \mathbb{R}$ with the metric given by

$
d(f,g)=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} 2^{-k} \min\{1,||f^{(k)}-g^{(k)}||_{\infty}\} ,
$

which isn't equivalent to any norm.

Comment: small formatting comment: `$||x||$` produces $||x||$  and `$\|x\|$` produces $\|x\|$

Comment: So the difference in output is the spacing?

Comment: Yes, excatly. Just compare these to expressions: $\||f|\|$ and $|||f|||$.

Comment: Actually the example of $C^\infty$ is quite nice for OPs last question, because $C^\infty(\mathbb{R})$ is not metrizable!

Comment: What topology are you giving it? Naturally, $f_n\to f$ in $C^{\infty}(\mathbb{R})$ if $f_n\to f$ in $C^{\infty}([-n,n])$ for every $n$, but this is convergence in countably many metrics, and hence, metric convergence. $C^{\infty}_c(\mathbb{R})$, however, isn't metric when given its usual topology.

Comment: @WoolierThanThou ups, of course I was think about then same. Mixed it up. Sorry!

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. What precisely does the norm allow so that we can't just say on a normal vector space that the metric is $x-y$?

Comment: $x-y$ is not, in general, a positive real number, so it can't be a metric. You can think of norms as metrics that interact in a slightly better way with algebraic operations - for instance the fact that $||\lambda x||=|\lambda|\cdot||x||$ for every scalar $\lambda$.

Comment: So what prevents us from somehow specifying a function that will take two vectors and return a positive real?

Comment: Well, said function would have to satisfy some conditions, right? And then, suddenly, you have to ask yourself how much your choice of random norm matters. For instance, following the comments above, there *is* a norm on the smooth functions on a compact set - the uniform norm. Nothing prevents you from defining it, but it doesn't *do* what you want it to, because this norm does not make differentiation continuous, so if you think that the derivative is an important aspect of a smooth function, then the uniform norm is simply a bad one.

Comment: One more question. In your answer what do you mean by the last sentence 'which isn't equivalent to any norm'?

Comment: Well, that there is the answer to your question: Could we have vector spaces that are just metric? Well, every norm gives you a metric, so question is: Does every metric give a norm. What does this mean? Well, given a metric, $d$, does there exist a norm $||\cdot||$ such that the open sets under $d$ are the same as the open sets under $||\cdot||$. I'm saying, if your vector space is $C^{\infty}(K),$ with the given metric, then there exists no such norm, so $C^{\infty}(K)$ is naturally a metric space (in fact, it is a Frechét space), but it is *not* a normed space.

Comment: I am new at this, so could you just please specify why we can't define a norm on this vector space you have given as example?

Comment: You *can* define some norm on this vector space, but it will give a *different* notion of open set, and thus, as topological (or metric) vector spaces, the two objects we'll have defined will be distinct. Showing this requires a bunch of machinery (the Arzela-Ascoli theorem for instance), so it might not be very telling if this is all new to you.

Comment: Can you please then explain it on the following simple example?https://www.quora.com/Why-are-all-metric-spaces-normed-spaces-but-not-vice-versa

Comment: Okay, I'd call that cheating, because this isn't a *vector space metric* on $\mathbb{R}$ - the vector space operations aren't continuous under this metric. But sure - a norm has to agree with scaling, so for any norm, we have $||\lambda x||=|\lambda|\cdot ||x||,$ implying that if $||\cdot||$ assumes any non-zero value, it has to assume all positive real values. In the example you give, the metric only assumes two values - 0 and 1.

Comment: Ok, but what do the return values of the metric have to do with specifying the norm? That is precisely what I am trying to understand. The fact that the metric always returns the same value does not prevent us to define the norm function differently, right? For example just take the absolute value of the real number given to the norm function.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/99557/discussion-between-woolierthanthou-and-michael-munta).

Answer (score 0):

If you have a normed vector space $(V,\|\cdot\|)$, simply by setting $d(u,v) := \|u-v\|$ for all $u,v \in V$ you can define and thus induce a metric on $V$. Of course there are other choices.

Now, a vector space is more an algebraic object because it combines *fields* and *groups*. Yet, you can always define at least a topology on those "normal Vector spaces" so that at least the scalar multiplication and the addition is continuous (called topological vector spaces). Many of these vector spaces you are familiar with also will allow for more structur, e.g. a metric or a norm. But there are (topological) vector spaces that for some topological reasons have to "many" open sets that it can been shown that those vector spaces are not metrizable in a nice and useful way.

That may sound cryptic but one key point here is the dimension of the given vector space. If it is finite, you are fine and actually every norm you can find is even equivalent. But when it comes to infinite dimensional vector spaces, things get vastly more interesting. Now, you have to be clear about one thing, when it comes to normed or metric spaces, the most important feature is the metric or norm. You can have the exact same set or vector spaces but endowe it with different norms and you get from a certain perspective very different objects.